# Missing pom spring-boot-dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot

There is a pom, pom.md5 and pom.shal missing for the latest version of the 
spring-boot-dependencies.

http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/

Not quite sure if this is the right way - but could somebody put them there or change the maven-metadata.xml to point at the former Build?

Edit:

Error during build process

```
Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-core:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-core:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.0.0.BUILD-20171005.042611-1 in spring.io.snapshot (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot) -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks

Edit2:

For the time being - until the issue is fixed - I did the following (not nice but works):

Excluded the spring-boot-dependencies in all the dependencies that have remotely something to do with spring boot.

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Added the spring-boot-dependencies dependency from maven central.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You know how to use those pom files? Have you tried http://start.spring.io/ ?

Comment: The issue is that maven-metadata.xml points to a new build and for that build the files I described are missing. - The result is this error during the build of my project: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-core:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.statemachine:spring-statemachine-core:jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.0.0.BUILD-20171005.042611-1 in spring.io.snapshot (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT build and not a milestone build of spring ?

Comment: We need a dependency in a version that didn't make it yet into a release.